# Razor Pages AJAX url id parameter

Tags: asp.net-ajax, razor-pages

I am trying to find reliable way to pass id parameter to the AJAX url.

I have a post method which should take id parameter:

```
 public ActionResult OnPostSend(int id)
        {
        //Some stuff which requires id parameter from page
        }
```

I also have AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Exercises/Details?handler=Send&id="+@Model.Exercise.ID,
            //other AJAX
        });
```

Please pay attention to the url parameter:

```
url: "/Exercises/Details?handler=Send&id="+@Model.Exercise.ID
```

It is the only way I have found how to pass id parameter to OnPostSend method. It works well. However this approach seems unrelible because I may change my routing to take some additional parameters that will make this code wrong.

Maybe someone knows better way how to pass id parameter to AJAX url. I have spend many time trying to figure it out but the best I have found mentioned above and seems like not very good solution to the problem.

Will be very greatfull for help!

Comment: check out `Url.Page` helper for [URL generation for Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#url-generation-for-pages)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I will be greatfull if you provide some example how to generate URL with both specific ID and handler using this method. I started google and try to apply this method but cant find appropriate overloads to satisfy these needs.

Comment: The over loads self explain what parameters are needed `@Url.Page(pageName: "Details", pageHandler: "Send", values: new { id = Model.Exercise.ID  }`. plus adding more parameters is a breaking change. no way for the helper to automagically know what values to put for the new parameters. If you update the parameters on the handler then you need to make the same update in the page.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Now its clear to me.

Comment: Mine is Working like you were trying!      `url: "/Books/Index?handler=DeleteBook&bookId=" + bookId` . I am passing bookId through function parameter into this ajax url. and its Working totaly fine like this. [Latest Update Core 2.2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out `Url.Page` helper for [URL generation for Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#url-generation-for-pages)

The UrlHelper extension over loads self explain what parameters are needed

```
url:"@Url.Page(pageName: "Details", pageHandler: "Send", values: new { id = Model.Exercise.ID }"
```

but adding more parameters is a breaking change.

There is no way for the helper to automagically know what values to put for the new parameters.

If you update the parameters on the handler then you need to make the same update in the page.